# Has anyone coded a Playa Multi Select Drop Panes UI in a Safecracker Form?

Tags: safecracker, playa, filter, multiselect

Can't find anything online about it... is it possible? Someone must have done this before? Please give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the safecracker syntax of {field:field_name} to get it to display exactly as it does in the CP / Publish page.